# Python Social Auth Django Github OAuth

Tags: python, django, oauth, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I'm trying to integrate my Django website with Github Authentication using Python-Social-Auth library

Configuration so far:

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
 ...
 "social_django",
 "social_core",

)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "account.auth_backends.UsernameAuthenticationBackend",
    "social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2",
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
            ...
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                "social_django.context_processors.backends",
                "social_django.context_processors.login_redirect",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**login.html**

```
<a href="{% url "social:begin" "GithubOAuth2" %}">Github</a>
```

**urls.py**

```
url("^socialaccounts/", include('social_django.urls', namespace='socialaccounts')),
```

But when I click the link, it shows a 404 Not Found Page. And where do I put the secret key and other github configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They go in the project's `settings.py` file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
 ...
 "social_django",
 "social_core",

)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "account.auth_backends.UsernameAuthenticationBackend",
    "social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2",
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
            ...
            'context_processors': [
                ...
                "social_django.context_processors.backends",
                "social_django.context_processors.login_redirect",
            ],
        },
    },
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_KEY = ''
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_SECRET = ''
```